# Trying to get data from Firebase realtime-database

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to get data from a realtine-database I have in Firebase.
I saw a few answers here but couldn't find a solution that I understood and worked for me.
this is my code:

```
func ReadTeamPlayers(teamName name: String, completion: @escaping ([Player]?) -> Void) {
    var playersArray = [Player]()
    ref.child(name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
            for dict in postDict {
                playersArray.append(Player(name: dict[snapshot.key] as! String, rank: dict[snapshot.value]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the player initializer I need to get the player's name and rank.
My Firebase looks like that:

```
TEAM1
   ---player1: 10
   ---player2: 5
   ---player3: 6
```

playerX is the player's name for now and the number is the player's rank.
How can I get the info for each player and use it later?
I tried few things but none worked for me.

Edit: I changed the code above to my current one, and this is the error I get now:

```
Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
dic.forEach {
    let player = Player(playerName:$0.key, playerRank:$0.value) 
    arr.append(player)
}
```

OR

```
let arr = dic.map { Player(playerName:$0.key, playerRank:$0.value)  }
```

---

Change response

```
func ReadTeamPlayers(teamName name: String, completion: @escaping ([Player]?) -> Void) {
```

---

```
func ReadTeamPlayers(teamName name: String, completion: @escaping ([Player]?) -> Void) {
    ref.child(name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let mPlayer = snapshot.value as? [String:Int] {
              var arr = [Player]()
              mPlayer.forEach {
               let player = Player(playerName:$0.key, playerRank:$0.value) 
               arr.append(player)
             }
             completion(arr)

        }else{
             completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try, but what is dic? I don't have a var named like that, and Dictionary gives me an error.

Comment: I edited the OP, with the change of the code and the error I get

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are using strange code with generics. Keep it simple

```
func ReadTeamPlayers(teamName name: String, completion: @escaping ([Player]?) -> Void) {
    var playersArray = [Player]()

    ref.child(name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            print("empty snapshot")
            return
        }

        for dict in dictionary {
            print("playerName = \(dict.key)")

            if let playerRank = dict.value as? Int {
                print("playerRank = \(playerRank)")

                let player = Player(name: dict.key, rank: playerRank)
                playersArray.append(player)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code above in the OP, could you please take a look>?

Comment: Thanks, this is now compiling.